# Can I limit the visible Collections in the Wagtail Admin Image Chooser?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a few Groups and Collections setup to take advantage of the Collections feature in wagtail.

I have limited *collection A* to *Administrators* only.

After logging in as a non-Administrator and clicking on the 'CHOOSE AN IMAGE' button to bring up the image chooser, there's a drop down for 'Collection' and it includes all of my collections, including the restricted *collection A*.

Is it possible to only show collections and images that the user owns similar to how the 'Images' menu item works?

Wagtail: 1.12.2
Django: 1.8.18

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been a while since this question was asked but hopefully this answer helps some people.

### Solution Overview

Wagtail 1.10 (as at this post, 2.10 is in development) introduced a helpful hook called [`construct_image_chooser_queryset`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#construct-image-chooser-queryset). This hook will intercept the images before being returned to the image chooser modal (used across all of Wagtail admin) and lets a developer customise what images are returned.

The hook also has access to the request, from there you can work out the user and build up your image query accordingly.

The other part of your question involved the collections drop-down field, this requires a bit of Django template work but is doable without too much extra complexity. Any [Wagtail admin template can be overridden](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/admin_templates.html) with a custom template, simply name it using the existing template path.

The Django shared template (include) that is used to render the collection dropdown, as at posting is [`wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html)

### Example Code

Note: the code is not a full solution as the question did not have the collection model changes but will be a good start hopefully.

#### 1. Wagtail image chooser queryset hook

- Based on the example in the [hooks documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#construct-image-chooser-queryset)
- file: wagtail_hooks.py

```py
from wagtail.core import hooks


@hooks.register('construct_image_chooser_queryset')
def show_my_uploaded_images_only(images, request):
    # Example: Only show uploaded images based on current user
    # actual filtering will need to be based on the collection's linked user group
    images = images.filter(uploaded_by_user=request.user)

    return images
```

#### 2. collection chooser template override

- 2a file: ../templates/wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html
- We want to override the template and redirect it to a custom one ONLY IF images are present in the template's context

```html
{% extends images|yesno:"base/include/images_collection_chooser.html,wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html" %}
```

- 2b file: ../templates/base/include/images_collection_chooser.html
- This template will only be used if there are images in the context
- Here we revise the context to remove images and **filter** collections then render the original Wagtail admin template

```html
{% load filter_with_permissions %}

{% with images=None %}
    {% with collections=collections|filter_with_permissions:user %}
      Images Only Collection Template:
      {% include "wagtailadmin/shared/collection_chooser.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

- 2c file: bakerydemo/base/templatetags/filter_with_permissions.py
- Here we make the Django [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) that does the collection filtering

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='filter_with_permissions')
def filter_with_permissions(collections, user):
    """ filter the collections based on current user """
    return collections.filter(name__startswith='B')  # actual filter to be done
```